# How to call another button's callback from a button created by code

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Suppose I have two pushbuttons on MATLAB GUI. When I press on pushMain, I want to call the callback of pushChild button.

I might have put simply pushChild_Callback(hObjects, eventdata, handles) in the pushMain's callback but my problem is I created pushChild object by code so there is no seperate callback function on the code.

```
handles.pushChild = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton');
handles.pushChild.Callback = {@printA, 1}
 % this means when I press on pushChild button, it will print "A = 1"

function printA(src, event, j)
handles = guidata(src);
fprintf('A = %d\n',j);
```

Now when I pressed on pushMain, I want to see "A = 1" on the screen.

I tried:

```
function pushMain(hObject, eventdata, handles)
fprintf('1\n');
fprintf('2\n');
fprintf('3\n');
handles.pushChild.Callback(); % option 1 -> no error but nothing happens.
handles.pushChild.Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % option 2 -> nothing happens
```

Regards.

Comment: It's unclear why you can't use `handles.pushMain.Callback = handles.pushChild.Callback`?

Comment: In pushMain's callback, I'm doing other things first. Calling the pushChild's callback is the pushMain's last operation.

Comment: Inside the parent callback you could do `feval( handles.pushChild.Callback, handles.pushChild, eventData, handles )` perhaps?

Comment: feval(handles.deleteButton{j-1}.Callback, handles.deleteButton{j-1}, eventdata, handles). This is what I tried but I got error: Error using feval, Function to evaluate must be represented as a string scalar, character vector, or function_handle object. handles.deleteButton{j-1} is nothing but a pushbutton.

Comment: handles.deleteButton{j-1} is an object but handles.deleteButton{j-1}.Callback is not an object.