# How to call a button's callback when pressing on another button in MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Suppose I have two pushbuttons on MATLAB GUI. When I press on pushMain, I want to call the callback of pushChild button.

```
function pushChild_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.A = 1;
guidata(hObject,handles);

function pushMain_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.B = 2;
pushChild_Callback(handles.pushChild, eventdata, handles) % option 1
pushChild_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % option 2
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

In both options, it goes to pushChild_Callback function when I press on pushMain button. However, it does not save the value of **handles.A**. Just after it leaves the pushChild_Callback function, handles.A becomes empty like I never filled it before. Therefore, I associate the problem with **guidata** command which is in the pushChild_Callback function. It does not save the handles into correct place..

Comment: Duplicate of [How to call another button's callback from a button created by code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742895/how-to-call-another-buttons-callback-from-a-button-created-by-code)

Comment: Do **not** repost questions. Your previous question was still active. Edit questions to improve them, don't repeat yourself. At least delete the old question as this one has an answer, and you put a better example.

Comment: how did you conclude that I repeat myself? I’m working on a GUI with more than 5000 lines of codes and many functions. These are seperate questions and I need them in different parts; for both two direct buttons with callback function on the code and one direct button, one button generated by code. I tried to make my problems as simple as possible and typed here..

Comment: Both questions have exactly the same issue - calling one button's callback from within another button's callback. I cannot see how solving one problem wouldn't solve both, and the syntax you've used is very similar in both. You're a new user here, I was just suggesting expected behaviour and site use.

Comment: I insist on this is a different question. I got the answer here but still looking for the other one. Can you please remove the sign 'This question may already have an answer here', because it does not.

Comment: @Wolfie I disagree that this is a duplicate question, they're quite clearly concerning different aspects of MATLAB gui design. This question is regarding passing data between functions using `guidata`, the other question you're referencing is regarding calling a callback function from within a different callback function. They're two completely separate concepts.

Comment: **1.** The titles are almost the same. **2.** The first sentence in each is *identical*, stating the aim of the question. **3.** In the first question you suggest one option is calling the child callback within the parent callback - something you clearly *do* in this question. **4.** That leaves the only difference as the "I tried to fix it by doing X", with different "X". **Summary:** I have no doubt you could solve both questions, as posed currently, with the same solution. If the other question is different, you should edit it to clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the handles data in `pushMain_Callback`, you're overwriting the changes made to `handles` by `pushChild_Callback`. This is because MATLAB is storing `handles` by value, not by reference. When you call `pushChild_Callback`, you're setting the value of `handles.A` only in the scope of this function. When you return back to the scope of `pushMain_Callback`, the local copy of handles does not have any value of `handles.A`. Thus, when you call `guidata(hObject,handles)` within `pushMain_Callback`, you are overwriting `handles` with a version that doesn't have `handles.A` set.

You need to refresh the `handles` data after you call your child function. I would suggest the following:

```
function pushChild_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.A = 1;
guidata(hObject,handles);

function pushMain_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles.B = 2;
pushChild_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
handles = guidata(hOject);
```

EDIT:

Basically, `guidata(hObject,handles)` is a *write* command, writing the value of `handles` to the `hObject` structure. `handles = guidata(hObject)` is a *read* command -- it reads the data stored within `hObject` and stores it in the variable `handles`. I'll try to explain step by step what's happening.

When you first call `pushMain`, `handles.B` gets set to 2, and the state of the variables looks like this:

```
pushMain: handles = {A = [], B = 2}
hObject: handles = {A = [], B = []}
pushChild: handles = {A = [], B = []}
```

When you call `pushChild`, you pass it the `handles` object from `pushMain`, so initially it looks like this:

```
pushMain: handles = {A = [], B = 2}
hObject: handles = {A = [], B = []}
pushChild: handles = {A = [], B = 2}
```

Then, `handles.A` gets set to 1. This updates only the value of `handles` within `pushChild` -- `pushMain` is unaffected, as its scope is different:

```
pushMain: handles = {A = [], B = 2}
hObject: handles = {A = [], B = []}
pushChild: handles = {A = 1, B = 2}
```

We then call `guidata(hObject,handles)`, which updates the value of `handles` stored by `hObject`:

```
pushMain: handles = {A = [], B = 2}
hObject: handles = {A = 1, B = 2}
pushChild: handles = {A = 1, B = 2}
```

Control now passes back to `pushMain`. Note that the value of `handles` within `pushMain` has *not* been updated, so `handles.A` is still empty. This means that if we were to call `guidata(hObject,handles)`, we set `hObject.handles.A = []`, which is obviously not what we want. Instead, we have to update the value of `handles`, which we do by calling `handles = guidata(hObject)`. Thus:

```
pushMain: handles = {A = 1, B = 2}
hObject: handles = {A = 1, B = 2}
pushChild: handles = {A = 1, B = 2}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much, it solved my problem. However, I could not understand the logic here. What's the difference between guidata(hObject) and guidata(hObject, handles)? Because I have also change in handles on pushMain. How does it save handles unless I type guidata(hObject, handles)?

Comment: The explanation is too long to fit in a comment, so I have edited the answer to try and explain the issue.

Comment: I'm confused with hObject. Isn't it the current object? For example, when the code is on pushMain, hObject is pushMain button, when its on pushChild, hObject is pushChild button. I think handles is more general thing because hObject is the same thing with handles.pushMain when the code runned is inside pushMain's callback.